# Find the GCD for given array of elements

Tags: java, algorithm

I had faced a interview question to find the gdc(greatest common divisor) for an integer array of element in optimised way :

```
Sample case :
   a[] = { 10,20,19,15,13}

Result = 1

sample case : 
  a[]={9,21,12,15,27}
Result : 3
```

I have submitted following result during the interview. But he asked to optimise the same. Solution which I proposesd:

```
package threeDpalm;

public class GCF
{
    public static void main(String ag [])
    {
        int[] input = {10, 20, 3, 30, 90, 40};
        boolean flag = true;
        int min_araay = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int count = 0;
        while (flag)
        {
            for (int j : input)
            {

                if (j < min_araay && j != 0)
                {
                    min_araay = j;
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < input.length; k++)
            {
                input[k] = input[k]%min_araay;
                if (input[k] == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count == input.length)
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        System.out.println(min_araay);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one please help me with better solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: This kind of question is better asking at [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: First step in gauging the quality of a prospective solution is making sure it solves the problem: does the above well on { 6, 9 }? Keep a map from prime factors seen to exponents, initialised with the factors of the first number. Once you processed all numbers, the product of the factors remaining in the map is the GC[DF]. For another number, check divisibility by each remaining entry in the map, removing entries if not divisible even once and lowering exponents if not divisible as often as all the numbers before. Starting with the smallest number may be worth a try.

Comment: @greybeard: Finding prime factorizations of large numbers is slow, but Euclid's algorithm is very fast and does not require factoring. The code here is not commented but it seems to be performing a version of Euclid's algorithm for several numbers.

Comment: @greyBeard: yes this work for the test case{6,9}. @ dougles : yes you are correct, it is a version of Euclid algo only ,but. as i said I was asked to give a more better solution. As i think the complexity is O(n).

Comment: @vinodbazari how do you even could dream of complexity of O(n)? your code complexity is obviously more than O(n) and as I said in my answer as far as I know this simple answer is the best case answer to this question. Also O(n) is not possible at all!

Comment: @Lrrr Even I think so.Its some where between O(n2) to O(n).Can you suggest a better way.

Comment: The complexity of Euclid's algorithm is nowhere close to theta(n). It is extremely fast, O(length(array) * log sum(values)). Your algorithm is fast enough. You do not need to find something faster than Euclid's algorithm. The interviewer asked you to optimize because he/she didn't understand your code and either wanted to save face or incorrectly thought it was slow. The likely cause is that your code is not readable. Describe the algorithm briefly in words and then use descriptive variable names. In two months you will not understand your own code if you don't make it readable.

Comment: Unfortunately, your algorithm is wrong. Examples: gcd(3, 5) = 1, but your program prints 2. gcd(12, 20, 30) = 2, but your program prints 6.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked on Code Review.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and the best way of computing GCD of a set is to compute GCDs one by one:

> GCD(a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>, ... ,a<sub>n</sub>) =
>   GCD(GCD(a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>),a<sub>3</sub>, ...
>   ,a<sub>n</sub>)

So you could do it like this :

```
private int gcdFunc(int a, int b){
    //TODO write this code.
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int gcd = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        gcd = gcdFunc(gcd, a[i]);
}
```

although your solution looks like a better solution but while loop looks very scary.